# selenium select option click error

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-crawler

HTML Code for crawler

```
<select size="10" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstMake" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstMake\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake">
    <option value="913163">Abarth</option>
    <option value="913229">Acura (USA / CAN)</option>
    <option value="910001">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option value="910066">Aro</option>
    <option value="910071">Asia</option>
    <option value="910002">Aston Martin</option>
    <option value="910052">Audi</option>
    <option value="910003">Austin</option>
    <option value="910004">Bentley</option>
    <option value="910005">BMW (EU)</option>
    <option value="913536">BMW (USA)</option>
    <option value="910072">Brabus</option>
...

</select>
```

Python Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://motul.lubricantadvisor.com/Default.aspx?data=1&amp;lang=ENG&lang=eng")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Select Car
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptCategoryBtn_ctl01_btnImage").click();

# Select Company (BMW Click)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake > option")))
company_option = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake"))
company_option.select_by_index(2)
```

error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyeongSic/PycharmProjects/crawler/SeriesCounter.py", line 17, in <module>
company_option.select_by_index(2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py", line 101, in select_by_index
self._setSelected(opt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py", line 212, in _setSelected
option.click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 77, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935     (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.1 x86_64)
```

I was try. It occured error why did it do that? I don't understand. I tried to another select-option sample. It didn't error but this isn't execute. could you let me know about this error?

add comment(Detail Image)

[image]

I need to make craling 'select the type'position automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://motul.lubricantadvisor.com/Default.aspx?data=1&amp;lang=ENG&lang=eng")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptCategoryBtn_ctl01_btnImage")))

driver.find_element(By.ID,"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptCategoryBtn_ctl01_btnImage").click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSelectedMake")))
driver.find_element(By.ID,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSelectedMake').click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake")))

drop=driver.find_element(By.NAME,'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstMake')
sel = Select(drop)
sel.select_by_visible_text('BMW (EU)')
```

In your code you are trying to click before the element become available on DOM

**Update 2: Based on New requirement Removed old code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://motul.lubricantadvisor.com/Default.aspx?data=1&amp;lang=ENG&lang=eng")

def getallcars():
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptCategoryBtn_ctl01_btnImage")))

    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptCategoryBtn_ctl01_btnImage").click()

    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSelectedMake")))
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSelectedMake').click()

    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake")))

    el = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstMake")
    car =[]
    for option in el.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'option'):
        car.append((option.text).encode('utf8'))
    return car

cars=getallcars()


for value in cars:
    drop = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake')
    sel = Select(drop)
    sel.select_by_visible_text(value)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.ID,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HeaderModel').click()
    el2 = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstModel")
    print "The models for %s are:"  %value
    for option in el2.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'option'):
        print  option.text
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(el2, 300, 200)
    action.click()
    action.perform()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HeaderMake').click()
```

this  code first get all values from dropdown and then select one after another and print the models present for that car

This is sample output for few cars:

```
The models for Abarth are:
500, 150 (2008 - )
Grande Punto, 199 (2007 - 2009)
Punto EVO, 199 (2010 - 2012)
Punto, 199 (2012 - 2014)
The models for Acura (USA / CAN) are:
CSX (2006 - 2011)
EL (2001 - 2005)
ILX (2012 - )
Integra (1996 - 2001)
MDX, YD1 (2001 - 2006)
MDX, YD2 (2007 - 2013)
MDX, YD3 (2013 - )
RDX, TB1 (2007 - 2012)
RDX, TB2 (2012 - )
RL, KA9, KB1, KB2 (2001 - 2012)
RLX (2013 - )
RSX, DC5 (2002 - 2006)
SLX, DJ5 (1996 - 1999)
TL, UA4, UA5 (2001 - 2003)
TL, UA6, UA7 (2004 - 2008)
TL, UA8, UA9 (2009 - 2014)
TSX, CL9 (2004 - 2008)
TSX, CU2 (2009 - 2014)
TLX (2014 - )
ZDX (2010 - 2013)
The models for Alfa Romeo are:
MiTo, 955 (2008 - )
33 (1983 - 1994)
145 (1994 - 2000)
146 (1994 - 2001)
147, 937 (2000 - 2010)
Giulietta, 940 (2010 - )
75 (1985 - 1992)
155 (1992 - 1997)
156 (1997 - 2007)
159, 939 (2005 - 2011)
90 (1984 - 1988)
164 (1987 - 1998)
166 (1998 - 2007)
GT (2004 - 2011)
GTV (1995 - 2005)
Brera (2006 - 2011)
Spider (1983 - 1993)
Spider (1995 - 2005)
Spider (2006 - 2011)
SZ, RZ (1989 - 1994)
4C (2013 - )
8C (2007 - 2010)
The models for Aro are:
10 (Duster) (1984 - 2006)
24 (1980 - 2006)
The models for Asia are:
Rocsta (1993 - 1999)
The models for Aston Martin are:
Cygnet (2011 - 2013)
V8 (1982 - 2001)
V8 Vantage (2005 - )
V12 Vantage (2010 - )
DB7 (1994 - 2004)
DB9 (2003 - )
Virage (2011 - 2012)
V12 Vanquish (2001 - 2007)
DBS (2008 - 2012)
Vanquish (2012 - )
Rapide (2010 - )
One-77 (2011 - 2012)
The models for Audi are:
A1, S1, 8X (2010 - )
A2, 8Z (2000 - 2005)
A3, S3 (1996 - 2003)
A3, S3, RS3, 8P (2003 - 2013)
A3 Cabriolet, 8P7 (2008 - 2013)
A3, S3, 8V (2012 - )
A3, S3 Cabriolet, 8V7 (2013 - )
80, RS2 (1986 - 1995)
90 (1985 - 1992)
Cabriolet (1991 - 2000)
Coupé, S2 (1986 - 1995)
A4, S4, RS4, 8D (1994 - 2001)
A4, S4, RS4, 8E (2001 - 2008)
A4, S4, RS4, 8K (2007 - )
A4 Allroad, 8KH (2009 - )
A5, S5, RS5, 8T (2007 - )
A5, S5, RS5 Cabriolet, 8F7 (2009 - )
100, S4 (1986 - 1994)
200 (1986 - 1989)
A6, S6, 4A (1994 - 1997)
A6, S6, RS6, 4B (1997 - 2005)
A6 Allroad, 4B (2000 - 2005)
A6, S6, RS6, 4F (2005 - 2011)
A6 Allroad, 4F (2006 - 2011)
A6, S6, RS6, 4G (2010 - )
A6 Allroad, 4G (2012 - )
A7, S7, RS7, 4G (2010 - )
V8 (1989 - 1994)
A8, S8, 4D (1994 - 2003)
A8, S8, 4E (2003 - 2010)
A8, S8, 4H (2010 - )
Q3, RS Q3, 8U (2011 - )
Q5, SQ5, 8R (2008 - )
Q7, 4L (2006 - 2015)
Q7, 4M (2015 - )
TT, 8N (1998 - 2006)
TT, TTS, TT RS, 8J3 (2006 - 2014)
TT, TTS, TT RS Roadster, 8J9 (2007 - 2014)
TT, TTS, FV3 (2014 - )
TT, TTS Roadster, FV9 (2014 - )
Quattro (1980 - 1987)
R8 Coupé, 423 (2007 - 2015)
R8 Spyder, 429 (2010 - 2015)
The models for Austin are:
MINI (1980 - 1991)
Metro (1983 - 1990)
Maestro (1984 - 1990)
Montego (1984 - 1990)
Ambassador (1983 - 1984)
The models for Bentley are:
Eight, Mulsanne (1986 - 1992)
Brooklands (1992 - 1999)
Turbo (1986 - 1999)
Continental, Azure (1986 - 2003)
Arnage (1998 - 2006)
Continental Flying Spur, B72 (2005 - )
Continental GT, B71 (2003 - )
The models for BMW (EU) are:
1-Series, E81 / E82 / E87 (2004 - 2013)
1-Series Convertible, E88 (2007 - 2013)
1-Series, F20 / F21 (2011 - )
2-Series, F22 (2013 - )
2-Series Convertible, F23 (2015 - )
2-Series Active Tourer, F45 (2014 - )
2-Series Gran Tourer, F46 (2015 - )
3-Series, E30 (1986 - 1992)
3-Series, E36 (1990 - 2001)
3-Series, E46 (1998 - 2006)
3-Series, E90 / E91 / E92 (2004 - 2013)
3-Series Convertible, E93 (2007 - 2013)
3-Series, F30 / F31 / F80 (2012 - )
3-Series Gran Turismo, F34 (2013 - )
4-Series, F32 / F82 (2013 - )
4-Series Convertible, F33 / F83 (2014 - )
4-Series Gran Coupé, F36 (2014 - )
5-Series, E34 (1988 - 1995)
5-Series, E39 (1995 - 2004)
5-Series, E60 / E61 (2003 - 2011)
5-Series Gran Turismo, F07 (2009 - )
5-Series, F10 / F11 (2010 - )
6-Series, E63 / E64 (2004 - 2011)
6-Series Coupé, F13 (2010 - )
6-Series Convertible, F12 (2011 - )
6-Series Gran Coupé, F06 (2012 - )
7-Series, E32 (1987 - 1994)
7-Series, E38 (1994 - 2001)
7-Series, E65 / E66 (2001 - 2008)
7-Series, F01 / F02 / F03 / F04 (2008 - 2015)
7-Series, G11 / G12 (2015 - )
8-Series, E31 (1990 - 1999)
i3, I01 (2013 - )
i8, I12 (2014 - )
X1, E84 (2009 - 2015)
X1, F48 (2015 - )
X3, E83 (2004 - 2010)
X3, F25 (2010 - )
X4, F26 (2014 - )
X5, E53 (1999 - 2007)
X5, E70 (2007 - 2013)
X5, F15 / F85 (2013 - )
X6, E71 / E72 (2008 - 2014)
X6, F16 / F86 (2014 - )
Z1, Z1 (1988 - 1992)
Z3, E36 (1995 - 2003)
Z4 Roadster, E85 (2002 - 2008)
Z4 Coupé, E86 (2006 - 2008)
Z4 Roadster, E89 (2008 - )
Z8, E52 (2000 - 2003)
The models for BMW (USA) are:
1-Series, E82 (2007 - 2013)
1-Series Convertible, E88 (2007 - 2013)
2-Series, F22 (2014 - )
2-Series Convertible, F23 (2014 - )
3-Series, E90 / E91 / E92 (2004 - 2013)
3-Series Convertible, E93 (2007 - 2013)
3-Series, F30 / F31 / F80 (2012 - )
3-Series Gran Turismo, F34 (2013 - )
4-Series, F32 / F82 (2013 - )
4-Series Convertible, F33 / F83 (2014 - )
4-Series Gran Coupé, F36 (2014 - )
5-Series, E60 / E61 (2003 - 2011)
The models for Brabus are:
smart (1998 - 2002)
A (1999 - 2004)
C (1991 - 2002)
E (1993 - 2002)
SLK/CLK (1997 - 2002)
S/SL/CL (1993 - 2005)
M (1993 - 2000)
V (1999 - 2002)
The models for Bugatti are:
Veyron (2005 - )
The models for Buick are:
Verano (2012 - )
Encore (2012 - )
Century (1996 - 2005)
Regal (1997 - )
LaCrosse, Allure (2004 - )
LeSabre (1999 - 2005)
Park Avenue (1991 - 2005)
Lucerne (2005 - 2011)
Terraza (2004 - 2007)
Rendezvous (2001 - 2007)
Rainier (2004 - 2007)
Enclave (2008 - )
The models for Cadillac (EU) are:
ATS (2013 - )
CTS(-V) (2013 - )
SRX (2012 - )
Escalade (2013 - )
The models for Cadillac (USA) are:
BLS (2006 - 2009)
ATS (2012 - )
CTS(-V) (2003 - )
XTS (2012 - )
Seville (1997 - 2004)
STS(-V) (2004 - 2011)
DeVille (1999 - 2005)
DTS (2006 - 2011)
XLR (2004 - 2009)
SRX (2004 - )
Escalade (2001 - )
ELR (2013 - )
The models for Chery are:
QQ6 (2006 - )
Chance / Niche (2008 - )
M11 / M12 (2008 - )
Tengo (2008 - )
A1 / J1 / Kimo (2007 - )
IndiS / X1 (2011 - )
A3 / E3 / Bonus (2008 - )
A5 / Fora / Elara (2006 - )
E5 (2012 - )
Arrizo (2013 - )
Riich (2009 - 2012)
J11 / Tiggo (2006 - )
Tiggo 5 (2014 - )
Boss (2006 - )
CrossEastar (2006 - )
The models for Chevrolet (EU) (Daewoo) are:
Tico (1991 - 1998)
Matiz, M200 / M250 (1998 - 2010)
Spark, M300 (2010 - 2014)
Lanos (1997 - 2002)
Kalos (2002 - 2008)
Aveo, T200 / T250 (2005 - 2011)
Aveo, T300 (2011 - 2014)
Nexia (1994 - 1997)
Lacetti (2004 - 2010)
Cruze, J300 / J305 / J308 (2009 - 2014)
Volt (2011 - 2014)
Nubira (1997 - 2010)
Tacuma / Rezzo (2000 - 2009)
Espero (1994 - 1999)
Leganza (1997 - 2002)
Evanda / Magnus, V200 (2002 - 2006)
Epica, V250 (2006 - 2012)
Malibu, V300 (2011 - 2015)
Chairman (2004 - 2008)
Trax / Tracker (2013 - 2014)
Captiva, C100 (2006 - 2011)
Captiva, C140 (2011 - 2014)
Orlando, J309 (2010 - 2014)
Camaro (2013 - )
The models for Chevrolet (RUS) are:
Spark (2011 - )
Aveo (2002 - )
Cobalt (2012 - )
Cruze, J300 (2009 - )
Epica (2006 - 2012)
Lacetti, J242E (2010 - )
Lanos (2002 - 2009)
Niva, VAZ 2123 (2002 - )
Rezzo (2002 - 2008)
The models for Chevrolet (USA) are:
Spark, M300 (2013 - )
Aveo, T250 (2008 - 2011)
Sonic, T300 (2012 - )
Cruze, J300 (2010 - )
Corsica (1989 - 1994)
Beretta (1989 - 1995)
Alero (1999 - 2004)
Cobalt (2005 - 2010)
Lumina (1994 - 2001)
Malibu (2000 - )
Malibu Maxx (2004 - 2007)
Volt (2011 - )
Impala (2000 - )
Monte Carlo (2000 - 2007)
SS (2014 - )
Camaro (1993 - )
Corvette (1983 - 2004)
Corvette, C6 (2005 - 2013)
Corvette, C7 (2014 - )
Trans Sport (1996 - 2004)
Uplander (2005 - 2008)
Captiva (2013 - 2014)
Trax (2015 - )
Traverse, GMT561 (2009 - )
HHR (2006 - 2011)
SSR (2004 - 2006)
Equinox (2005 - )
Colorado (2006 - 2012)
Colorado (2015 - )
Blazer (1994 - 2005)
TrailBlazer (2001 - 2009)
Tahoe (1999 - 2005)
Tahoe, GMT921 (2006 - 2013)
Tahoe (2015 - )
Express, GMT600 (1997 - 2002)
Express, GMT601 (2003 - )
Suburban, GMT830 (1999 - 2006)
Suburban, GMT931 (2007 - 2013)
Suburban (2015 - )
Avalanche, GMT805 (2001 - 2006)
Avalanche, GMT940 (2007 - 2013)
Silverado, GMT800 (2002 - 2006)
Silverado, GMT901 (2006 - 2013)
Silverado (2014 - )
The models for Chrysler (EU) are:
ES (1986 - 1990)
Delta (2011 - 2014)
Ypsilon (2011 - 2015)
Saratoga (1990 - 1994)
PT Cruiser (1999 - 2010)
Vision (1993 - 1997)
GS (1988 - 1991)
GTS (1988 - 1991)
Neon (1994 - 2005)
New Yorker (1988 - 1991)
Sebring (2000 - 2010)
Stratus, Cirrus (1994 - 2000)
300M (1998 - 2004)
300C (2005 - 2010)
300C, LX (2011 - 2015)
(Grand) Voyager, RT (1986 - 2015)
The models for Chrysler (USA / CAN) are:
Aspen (2006 - 2009)
Crossfire (2003 - 2009)
Neon (1999 - 2002)
GS (1988 - 1991)
Le Baron (1988 - 1995)
PT Cruiser (1999 - 2010)
Sebring (2000 - 2010)
200 (2011 - )
300M (1998 - 2004)
300(C) (2005 - 2010)
300, LX (2011 - )
Newport (1988 - 1991)
New Yorker (1988 - 1991)
Fifth Avenue (1988 - 1989)
Pacifica, CS (2003 - 2008)
(Grand) Voyager / Town & Country, RT (1986 - )
The models for Citroën are:
2CV (1984 - 1991)
LNA (1984 - 1988)
AX (1986 - 1997)
C-Zero (2010 - )
C1 (2005 - 2014)
C1, B4 (2014 - )
Axel (1984 - 1990)
ZX (1991 - 1998)
C2 (2003 - 2010)
Visa (1984 - 1988)
Saxo (1996 - 2003)
DS3, A55 (2010 - )
C3 / Pluriel (2001 - 2009)
C3, A51 (2009 - )
C3 Picasso (2009 - )
Xsara (1997 - 2005)
Xsara Picasso (1999 - 2011)
C-Elysée (2013 - )
C4 (2004 - 2010)
C4, B71 (2010 - )
DS4, B75 (2011 - )
C4 Cactus (2014 - )
C4 Aircross (2012 - )
C4 Picasso (2007 - 2013)
C4 Picasso, B78 (2013 - )
Grand C4 Picasso (2006 - 2013)
Grand C4 Picasso, B78 (2013 - )
GSA (1984 - 1987)
BX (1982 - 1995)
Xantia (1993 - 2001)
C5 (2000 - 2009)
C5, X7 (2008 - )
CX (1983 - 1992)
XM (1989 - 2001)
DS5 (2011 - )
C6 (2006 - 2013)
Evasion / Synergie (1994 - 2002)
C8 (2002 - 2013)
C-Crosser (2007 - 2012)
Nemo Multispace (2007 - )
Berlingo Multispace (1996 - 2008)
Berlingo Multispace, B9 (2008 - )
Jumpy- / Dispatch Multispace (2007 - )
Jumper- / Relay Combi (2007 - )
The models for Dacia are:
Previous models (1984 - 1999)
Supernova, B41 (2000 - 2003)
Solenza, B41 (2003 - 2005)
Sandero, B90 (2008 - 2012)
Sandero II, B52 (2012 - )
Logan, L90\K90 (2004 - 2012)
Logan II, L52\K52 (2012 - )
Duster, H79 (2009 - )
Lodgy, J92 (2012 - )
Dokker, K67 (2013 - )
The models for Daihatsu (EU) are:
Cuore / Mira / Domino (1978 - 1998)
Cuore / Mira / Charade (1998 - 2013)
Trevis (2006 - 2009)
Move (1996 - 2003)
Gran Move (1996 - 2003)
Sirion (1998 - 2005)
Sirion 2 (2005 - 2010)
Young RV (YRV) (2000 - 2007)
Charade (1983 - 2001)
Charade (2011 - 2013)
Valéra (1994 - 2001)
Charmant (1981 - 1987)
Applause (1989 - 2001)
Materia (2006 - 2011)
Terios (1997 - 2012)
Feroza / Sportrack (1988 - 1999)
Taft (1974 - 1984)
Rocky / Fourtrack (1984 - 2003)
Copen (2003 - 2012)
The models for Daihatsu (RUS) are:
Mira (1998 - )
Coo (2006 - 2011)
Be-go (1997 - )
Copen (2003 - )
The models for Daimler are:
Six / Double Six (1995 - 1998)
V8 (1998 - 2002)
Super Eight (2003 - 2007)
The models for Datsun (RUS) are:
mi-Do (2014 - )
on-Do (2014 - )
The models for Dodge (EU) are:
Caliber, PM (2006 - 2012)
Avenger (2007 - 2010)
Viper, ZB (2003 - 2010)
Nitro, KA (2006 - 2010)
Journey (2007 - 2011)
The models for Dodge (USA / CAN) are:
Neon / SX (1994 - 2005)
Dart, PF (2012 - )
Caliber, PM (2006 - 2012)
Avenger (2007 - 2014)
Shadow (1986 - 1990)
Challenger (2009 - )
Charger, LX (2006 - )
Magnum (2004 - 2008)
Nitro, KA (2006 - 2012)
Journey (2007 - )
Stratus, Cirrus (1994 - 2000)
(Grand) Caravan (2004 - )
Durango, HB (2004 - )
Dakota, ND (2004 - 2011)
Viper, ZB (2003 - 2010)
Viper, VX (2013 - )
The models for DR are:
DR Zero (2015 - )
DR1 (2009 - 2012)
DR2 (2010 - )
DR5 (2007 - )
CityCross (2011 - )
```

Comment: Thanks your support. but I have really problem. I want to make loop crawler. something like.  Audi then then Bentley BMW(EU).  Have you know do that?

Comment: you want to scroll on all values of options?

Comment: @You.Brighton..i have provided a way to get all options of car first and then select all values in dropdown..Note this is hint code & might not be the exact solution for your problem...please explain problem in detail for better understanding

Comment: I'm sorry this is my mistake. I'll try writing detail next time. and I tired yours scecond code. but It doesn't work. once and for all would you see the main question. I uploaded the image explain

Comment: means you require models details in your console for all car models after selecting the car or you want to select all options

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate it.  first I tired. I wander a little. but I found line 25 line in update2 code so I changed "car.append((option.text).encode('utf8'))" to "car.append(option.text)". It does work very well

Comment: can I get more question? if I want to use "wait.until" instead of time.sleep how can I use the method?

Comment: ok. I made the question. this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601388/selexbox-present-check-error-at-selenium

Answer (score 0):

You should change
`wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake > option")))` to `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake > option")))`