# selexbox present check error at selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

## Code at Selenium by python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://motul.lubricantadvisor.com/Default.aspx?data=1&amp;lang=ENG&lang=eng")

def getallcars():
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptCategoryBtn_ctl01_btnImage")))

    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptCategoryBtn_ctl01_btnImage").click()

    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSelectedMake")))
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblSelectedMake').click()

    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake")))

    el = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstMake")
    car =[]
    for option in el.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'option'):
        car.append((option.text).encode('utf8'))
    return car

cars=getallcars()


for value in cars:
    drop = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstMake')
    sel = Select(drop)
    sel.select_by_visible_text(value)
    time.sleep(2) #<---- THIS POINT!!
    driver.find_element(By.ID,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HeaderModel').click()
    el2 = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstModel")
    print "The models for %s are:"  %value
    for option in el2.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'option'):
        print  option.text
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(el2, 300, 200)
    action.click()
    action.perform()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HeaderMake').click()
```

I have been make the crawler. I don't understand completely yet. so I have a question. maybe It's 34line at code. I was mark about #
it's use be the `"time.sleep(2)"` method. because It didn't detect the select box when It's change about "`sel.select_by_visible_text(value)`"

how can I do that? I don't want to use the "`time.sleep(2)`"method.
already I tried "`expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located`" It doesn't work. I guess It's problem about dropbox. this size is not basically because It did well when I tried another size tried "`expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located`"

Comment: do you get error message ? Show it in question.

Comment: can you tell why you want to remove  time.sleep()

Comment: @thebadguy sorry I'm late. I was fix the computer. I came back down to business. your example is very well. this problems is not very important. I occur some trouble just in case when I have disconnect about internet a while.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit wait will not work, because the conditions you can use are "element to be clickable", "element to be visible" and like that.
The element that you using for explicit wait is available and clickable also, but its failing because other element is overlapping it.

Since the other element's overlap takes time to disappear, we have to wait for the overlap to disappear before we can click on the element.
Explicit wait can wait for element to appear and clickable, which it is already is but it is being hidden by other element.

In this scenario, we have to use time.sleep() to put a hard wait

Comment: ok I got. so how about while statement? wait.sleep -> dropbox click-> check element with before element -> wait.sleep -> dropbox click ->check element again with before element. sorry. this is my attachment. I want to make code perfectly